# How to install redisearch module in GCP memorystore redis instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore, redisearch

I need to install the RediSearch module on top of a GCP memorystore redis instance.

### I followed the steps:

`docker run -p 6379:6379 redislabs/redisearch:latest`

I pushed this docker image to a Kubernetes cluster and exposed the external IP. I used that external IP and the 6379 port as [configuration for my application](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/java_client.html) but I'm not able to connect to RediSearch.

### code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import io.redisearch.client.Client;
import io.redisearch.*;


public class RediSearch {



    static Client client = new Client("testdoc1", "clusteripaddress", 8097);
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RediSearch.class);

    public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {

        @Description("gcp project id.")
        @Default.String("XXXX")
        String getProjectId();
        void setProjectId(String projectId);
    }

    public static PipelineResult run(Options options) throws IOException {

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        pipeline.apply(Create.of("test"))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {     
                String pubsubmsg = c.element();                 

                Schema sc = new Schema()
                .addTextField("title", 5.0)
                .addTextField("body", 1.0)
                .addNumericField("price");

            client.createIndex(sc, Client.IndexOptions.Default());

            Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            fields.put("title", "hello world");
            fields.put("body", "lorem ipsum");
            fields.put("price", 800);
            fields.put("price", 1337);
            fields.put("price", 2000);

            client.addDocument("searchdoc3", fields);

            SearchResult[] res = client.searchBatch(new Query("hello world").limit(0, 5).setWithScores());      

            for (Document d : res[0].docs) {
                LOG.info("redisearchlog{}",d.getId().startsWith("search"));
                LOG.info("redisearchlog1{}",d.getProperties());
                LOG.info("redisearchlog2{}",d.toString());
            }


            }
        }));    


        return pipeline.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(Options.class);
        run(options);

    }
}
```

### Error :

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:59)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:234)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15)
at io.redisearch.client.Client._conn(Client.java:137)
at io.redisearch.client.Client.getAllConfig(Client.java:275)
at com.testing.redisearch.RediSearch$1.processElement(RediSearch.java:59)
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host xxxxxxxxxxx:6379
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:204)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:100)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1894)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:349)
at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:234)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:15)
at io.redisearch.client.Client._conn(Client.java:137)
at io.redisearch.client.Client.getAllConfig(Client.java:275)
at com.testing.redisearch.RediSearch$1.processElement(RediSearch.java:59)
at com.testing.redisearch.RediSearch$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:411)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:380)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:305)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:140)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:120)
at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:181)
... 31 more
```

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share with us more information. For example how you are trying to connect from Kubernetes to the Redis?

Comment: @chainicko 1. first i pushed the redisearch docker image to container registry (docker run -p 6379:6379 redislabs/redisearch:latest) 2. and i ran the docker command and exposed the cluster nodes (external host) 3. in the code configure the external host and port and tried to run but not able to connect

Comment: @chainicko plese check my code above in code block

Comment: Please have a look into the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-gke#sample_application) and check if you are stablishing correctly a connection to a Redis instance from a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster. Meanwhile could you please share the error which you get in Stackdriver Logging when you try to connect?

Comment: Thanks for your reply chainicko , Error updated above (error block)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to have the RediSearch module in your memorystore instance, it appears that may not be supported yet. You can see in [the google cloud docs here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/supported-versions) that at the time of writing this, even for version 5.0, redis modules are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple causes as per the error `JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool`. According to the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13043658/10810527) the problem is that the connection to RediSearch couldn't be established, be it because Redis is not running, the connection times out or it cannot be allocated.

Regardless, I have noticed that even though you deploy Redis on port 6379, in your code you are trying to access it on port 8097. Please change your Client declaration to the following and retry the connection.

```
static Client client = new Client("testdoc1", "<cluster_ip_address>", 6379);
```